# javascript function first prompt incorrect if user don't write anything, cancelle or to short name. Then second prompt cannot display

Tags: javascript, function

I am beginner at javascript and I am looking for solution.
The problem I have is, when the user won't write anything, cancelle prompt or write to short then the second prompt cannot display.

So far I can't find it. I know it has the do with something about != but can't figure it out.

The second prompt is still showing up no matter what..

Anyone can help me out?

```js
        function namen(voornaam, achternaam) {

            if ( voornaam === "") {
                return "niks is ingevuld"
            }

            else if ( voornaam == null) {
                return "je hebt geanulleerd"
            }

            else if (voornaam == voornaam.substring(0,2)) {
                return "Te weinig ingevuld"
            }

            else {
                return voornaam.charAt(0).toUpperCase().substring() + voornaam.slice(1)
            }

        }

            let naam1 = prompt("geef je voornaam");
            let naam2 = prompt("Geef jouw achternaam")
            let aangepast = namen(naam1, naam2);
            document.write(`<p>Test ${aangepast}</p>`);
```

Answer (score 0):

In short: Check the first prompt's result before prompting the second time.

---

Following the [control flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow), we can see that:

1. The first `prompt()` is called.
2. The second `prompt()` is called.
3. *Then* the inputs are checked.

To prevent the second call to `prompt()`, we need to use a [conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming)) [branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_(computer_science)): We only want to call prompt twice if the first input is valid. In pseudo-code:

```
firstInput = prompt();
if (firstInput is valid) {
  prompt();
}
```

But we want to use the result of the second `prompt()` later, so its variable needs to be declared in the [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) in which it will be used. We need to let JavaScript know where our variable exists by declaration:

```js
let firstInput = prompt();
let secondInput; // Declaring the variable in this scope

if (firstInput !== null) {
  // First prompt was not cancelled
  
  secondInput = prompt(); // Prompt in if-block
}

secondInput; // Can be used now; *may* contain prompt's result
```

Compare the above to this faulty code. Here, the second prompt's variable is declared in a narrower scope, so the wider scope is unaware of it:

```js
let firstInput = prompt();

if (firstInput !== null) {
  let secondInput = prompt(); // Declaration in a narrow scope
}

secondInput; // Not known ("defined") in this wider scope; will throw a ReferenceError
```

---

To have a more sophisticated validation check, you may want to use a boolean function. Example:

```js
const input = prompt();
if (isValid(input) === false) {
  console.log("Error: Your input is not valid!");
}

function isValid(text) {
  if (text === null) {
    // This applies if prompt was cancelled; consider it invalid
    return false;
  }

  if (text.length < 2) {
    // If less than 2 characters are entered, consider it invalid
    return false;
  }
  
  // If above conditions were met, consider text valid
  return true;
}
```

That function can be reused later, e.g. in your `namen` function:

```js
const input = prompt();
if (isValid(input) === false) {
  console.log("Error: Your input is not valid!");
}

const insertText = getText(input);
document.body.append(insertText);

function isValid(text) {
  if (text === null) {
    return false;
  }
  if (text.length < 2) {
    return false;
  }
  
  return true;
}

// Analogous example to your 'namen' function
function getText(text) {
  if (isValid(text)) {
    return "You entered: " + text;
  } else {
    return "Something was invalid.";
  }
}
```

---

**Note that [`document.write()` is discouraged](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dynamic-markup-insertion.html#dom-document-write-dev)**. Prefer to use [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to create elements and add their content with [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), [`append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) or similar. Example:

```js
const em = document.createElement("em"); // <em></em>
em.textContent = "This paragraph"; // <em>This paragraph</em>

const p = document.createElement("p"); // <p></p>
p.append(em); // <p><em>This paragraph</em></p>
p.append(" is important."); // <p><em>This paragraph</em> is important.</p>

document.body.append(p); // Add to <body>
```